# Connecting to sources in the Integrated File System folders on an AS400 using power center

Tags: ibm-midrange, ifs

Like to connect to iSeries Integrated File System folders using Power Center Informatica, not sure how to set up the connection.

Answer (score 1):

maybe [netserver](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-netserver) ?  That is what is used to map a network drive from windows to the IFS.

netserver may already be installed on your ibm i.

```
addlible netserver
go nets
```

then use option `11. Work with shares` to add a share.